# mysql get the yesterday flag(another column not datetime type)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have query for get the the datetime of clockout-1 day, but not for the flag column in that day's row, but current row. this is my query

```
SELECT clockin, clockout, flag FROM `attendance` 
WHERE (`flag` IN ('A', 'AC')) 
AND (`clockin` BETWEEN '2021-03-26' AND '2021-04-26') 

AND (IF( DATE_FORMAT(clockout - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%H:%i:%s') < '23:00:00' 

-- my problem in this condition 
AND (flag = 'A' || flag ='AC'), 

((CAST(clockin AS time) > '08:15:01')), ((CAST(clockin AS time) > '12:15:01'))))
                AND (CAST(clockin AS time) < '14:00:00') 
                    
            ORDER BY `user_id`
```

I miss one that in the condition, I use flag in that row not flag from (date-1 day)'s row. how I can get flag from (date-1 day)'s row not current row?

Comment: Use `lag()` to access  a previous row column`

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(clockout - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%H:%i:%s') < '23:00:00'` makes no sense. Substracted **days** cannot alter **time**.

Comment: if I use `lag()` that access previous row, but in the table that can't be, because previous row can be row from another user_id. @Serg

Comment: @RahmatHidayat, you control partitioning and ordering with over() clause of the window function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: @serg thanks it solved with ordering by user_id and clockin